# In my city and in my country without "there"

Tags: word-choice

Can I start my sentence with "in my country" "in my city" without adding "there"? In sentences #1 and #2?

1."In my country the most interesting place is an old town by the sea. 2.In this place are so many old buildings from different epochs. You can see them in one day. You can walk there all day because the town isn't small. People there see interesting monuments and houses."

Comment: The phrasing of your *first* example doesn't easily allow us to include ***there** [is]*. With your second example *(In this place are so many old buildings)*, it's "literary / poetic" to omit the word ***there*** before ***are*** (in practice, with nothing else to go on, it's more likely to be just an indicator that the speaker isn't a native Anglophone). My advice is; don't "experiment" with discarding the word ***there*** in such contexts. Just accept that *sometimes*, native speakers might do this (but it's probably not a good idea to copy them).

Comment: Note that older Biblical texts will have [*In my Father’s house are many rooms*](https://biblehub.com/john/14-2.htm) where in more recent versions it's more likely to be  *In my Father’s house **there** are many rooms*.

Comment: Do I understand correctly "there" cannot be used in the first sentence as it is given. Right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"there" cannot be used in the first sentence as it is given.* It's certainly possible to add "There" to the *start* of the utterance. Obviously there are far more contexts where you might reasonably preface an assertion with ***Here** in my country...*, since most people are in their own country most of the time. But if you're abroad at time of utterance, ***There** in my country we hang litterbugs* is syntactically fine. But that's not the same as "existential" ***there is / there are*** as used in your second example, where ***there*** is "optional".

Comment: I mean it can be added to the start of the of the sentence, but isn't it the only place where it can be used in that sentence? I mean can it be added  to the end or the middle of the sentence?

Comment: No, it's syntactically impossible to insert the single extra word "there" anywhere in your first example, apart from as per my previous comment (where did you *think* you might be able to put it?). But if you remove the words "the most interesting place" (syntactically, the ***explicit subject***) you're left with the same structure as your *second* example, in which case you can include "there" before "is" (or not; it's the same stylistic choice as described earlier, with exactly the same implications).

Comment: Thank you!  That's very interesting.

Comment: note that an utterance like ***There is** nothing left to say* doesn't really have an "explicit subject", syntactically speaking. But it's clearly present in the "standard, default" Subject-Verb-Object sequence in English: ***Nothing** is left to say*.

Comment: I am really interested in such nuances. But I can't usually find them in my books. :(

Comment: Well, bear in mind that to speakers of many other languages, #1 *In my house are two televisions* and #2 *Two televisions are In my house* look perfectly okay (especially if *their* native language uses constructions like that, so it looks more like word-for-word translation). BUT to native Anglophones, the first of these is dated / poetic, and the second is appallingly non-idiomatic. Don't be suckered into using those forms yourself - they will almost *never* be "suitable", even though they're both perfectly okay syntactically.

Comment: I will rephrase again to make sure I don't misunderstand. "There (or without "there") in my country the most interesting place is an old town by the sea." This is the only place where I can use "there".  I can remove "the most interesting place" and say "There in my country is an old town by the sea." And also if  I understand correctly "there" can be used after "country": "In my country there is an old town by the sea." If I omit it and say "In my country is an old town..." it's a poetic/literary use or a mistake made by a non-native speaker in case they don't know anything about this use.

Comment: All of what you just said is absolutely correct. EXCEPT although it's true that *There in my country is an old town by the sea* is in principle syntactically valid", it's an incredibly unlikely utterance. Someone might say *There at the bottom of the garden is my shed* (probably while *pointing* at it). And feasibly in a children's book you might find *There at the bottom of the garden lived the fairies*. But these are ***so*** unlikely in most contexts it would probably be safer for you to assume those versions simply aren't "valid" in the first place.

Comment: ...if you ***start*** an utterance with ***There** [locational adverbial phrase] **is** [something]*, the word "there" always means "over there (as opposed to **here**). But without an adverbial phrase such as ***in** my country, **at** the bottom of the garden,...* the utterance would just start with "existential" ***there is*** (which simply asserts the ***existence*** of something - the word "there" has nothing to do with "location" in that usage).

Comment: Note that "existential" ***There is** a coin in my hand* is fine, but "locational" ***There in my hand** is a coin* is incredibly unlikely (though ***Here in my hand** is a coin* is fine). Does that help?

Comment: Also note that *People there see interesting monuments and houses* is "weird", because when you put the "adverb of place" ***there*** immediately after the ***subject*** ("people"), it would be most naturally interpreted as meaning ***people who live there***. So it would be fine with, say, *[The] People there speak a strange dialect*. But if the "subject" people are *non-locals*, you need to put the adverb ***after the verb*** (and after the "object" if there is one, so *People [can] see interesting monuments and houses there*).

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I will copy and paste everything  into my notes. If while writing your explanations down, I will have a question, can I ask you another question again?

Comment: I can't guarantee I'll always be aware of your follow-on questions and be able to respond - but in principle that's fine, yes.

Comment: I will re-read  each explanation tomorrow. I appreciate your help.:)